# PhoneGap Your Binary is not optimized for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to upload my first iPhone app using Application Loader, but when I try so I get the following error:

[image: Application Loader Error]

Since I've tried everything according to the similar Questions here, I think there is a different problem.

This is in my config.xml:

```
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon120x120.png" gap:platform="ios" width="120" height="120"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon60x60.png" gap:platform="ios" width="60" height="60"/>
<icon src="res/icon/ios/Icon180x180.png" gap:platform="ios" width="180" height="180"/>
<gap:splash src="Default.png" gap:platform="ios" width="320" height="480"/>
<gap:splash src="Default@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="960"/>
<gap:splash src="Default-568h@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="640" height="1136"/>
<gap:splash src="Splash750x1334.png" gap:platform="ios" width="750" height="1334"/>
<gap:splash src="Splash480x320.png" gap:platform="ios" width="480" height="320"/>
<gap:splash src="Splash960x640.png" gap:platform="ios" width="960" height="640"/>
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait.png" gap:platform="ios" width="768" height="1024"/>
<gap:splash src="Default-Portrait@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1536" height="2048"/>
<gap:splash src="Default-Landscape.png" gap:platform="ios" width="1024" height="768"/>
```

All images are in the root folder.

+I'm using PhoneGap Build.

Comment: My usual tip for PGB, having used it a lot, is to delete and reload it all when you get these issues. According to the docs you've done it right after all.

Comment: Deleted it and reloaded, still get the same error..

Comment: Then double check your images and their sizes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem and got it compiled to the App Store! I used http://pgicons.abiro.com to generate images and used their sample config.xml to link the images, works perfectly!